# Files are red in terminal after transferring files via usb drive

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am a Mac user and I recently decided to put some files from one of my older computer's onto my new one by usb drive.  I noticed when I was in the terminal all the files were labeled red and are normally supposed to be grey.
Any idea what might be the cause of this?
Here is an example picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HVg6.png)

Comment: What does `ls -l` print?

Comment: According to which rules do you have your files coloured? What command are you using to display the file names?